# CSS class multiple times in one file

Tags: html, css

I have a html file with a div like

```
<div id="mydiv" class="mydiv">...</div>
```

In that html, I have one css file (mycss.css) linked.

at 600th line of that css file, I have

```
#mydiv
{
   float:left;
   background-image: url(divimg1.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width:44px;
   height:43px;
}
```

at 700th line, in the same css file, I have

```
#mydiv
{
   background-image: url(divimg2.svg);
}
```

Now, most of the time I am getting divimg2 but very rarely/intermittently I am getting divimg1. I was under impression that when browser reads css files, it read top to bottom and closest one that means divimg2 should appear all the time. What am I missing.

I understand there shouldn't be two occurrences of same class but here I am looking for why for the above case, behaviour is intermittent?

Answer (score -1):

Use `important` tag in CSS to get first preference.

```
#mydiv
{
   background-image: url(divimg2.svg) !important;
}
```

Comment: The keyword `!important` is like a development _cheat mode_ - it's not really for production. It will be sufficient to edit the first `background-image` reference and delete the second.